# apache HTTP webserver for IOS app

Tags: php, ios, apache, mysqli, swift4

I have a simple question. I have a website that runs on php/Mysqli and apache. Can I use the same stack for my IOS. Can I use Apache HTTP as my backend server for my IOS app. If it is not possible what backend server do you suggest other than firebase

Comment: please clarify: do you want to run php on iOS or _access_ your apache backend from an iOS app? (answer to second: yes, of course)

Comment: yes access apache backend from Ios. Basically access my apache server. Pull data from my database and Display on an IOS app

Comment: so the answer is a simple yes. Just create a http request in ios to that server.

Comment: thanks alot. just a simple question if this is the case why people use firebase or parse?

Comment: firebase is just a cloud database that serves a REST Api, (as far as I understood from 1 minute googeling). But you can of course use your own api.

Comment: thanks I got it now. Thanks for the help